# Update reports from jasperserver

Tags: java, ireport, jasperserver

I just took over a project which is about JasperReports. The problem is that all that I have are reports on the JasperServer (3.5) repository.

When I connect to the repository using iReport, I cannot change directly on the server. When I click on some of the report from repository (using iReport) it opens some temporary file (like file_123112312.jrxml) and all changes on that file are not reflected in the repository. I also try to "publish" report but iReport gives me wizard to deploy as a new report (which I don't want, I only want to change existing one).

Is there any way I can use those reports (and change them in iReport) since I don't have source .jrxml files, only files from the repository?

Thanks

Comment: what repository are you using for the reports?

Comment: I found the solution here: http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=112&forumid=102&topicid=92615

Comment: @Nikola May be you should convert your comment to answer?

Comment: Just posting the link is not an answer.  Since the link is now dead this answer has been lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is here:

http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=112&forumid=102&topicid=92615#92616

Comment: This link is dead.